# General form of Matrix family

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the general form of matrices $^1U,^2U,^3U \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$such that $^iU$ is nonsingular and for every permutation $\pi  : \left[{3} \right] \rightarrow \left[{3} \right]$ $^1U^{\pi\left( {1} \right)},^2U^{\pi\left( {2} \right)},^3U^{\pi\left( {3} \right)}$  are linearly dependent.

If we allow 2 of the matrices to be diagonal then I believe the only form is proportional to:
$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

But for general nonsingular matrices?

Comment: Hmm, what does the symbol $^1U^{\pi(1)}$ mean? Is it the $\pi(1)$-th column of the matrix $^1U$?

Comment: @user1551: Exactly